# Filter array, store adjacency information

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

Let's say I have an 2D `array` of `(N, N)` shape:

```
import numpy as np
my_array = np.random.random((N, N))
```

Now I want to do some computations only on some "cells" of this array, for instance the ones inside the central part of the array. To avoid doing computations on cells I'm not interested in, what I usually do here is create a Boolean mask, in this spirit:

```
my_mask = np.zeros_like(my_array, bool)
my_mask[40:61,40:61] = True
my_array[my_mask] = some_twisted_computations(my_array[my_mask])
```

But what if `some_twisted_computations()` involves values of the neighboring cells if they are inside the `mask`? Performance-wise, would it be a good idea to create an "adjacency array" with a `(len(my_mask), 4)` shape, storing the index of 4-connected neighbor cells in the flat `my_array[mask]` array that I will use in `some_twisted_computations()`? If yes, what are the efficient options for computing such adjacency array? Should I switch to lower-level langage/other data structures?

My real-worlds arrays shapes are around `(1000,1000,1000)`, the mask concerns only a small subset (~100000) of these values and is of rather complex geometry. I hope my questions make sense...

EDIT: the very dirty and slow solution I've worked out:

```
wall = mask

i = 0

top_neighbors = []
down_neighbors = []
left_neighbors = []
right_neighbors = []
indices = []

for index, val in np.ndenumerate(wall):
    if not val:
        continue
    indices += [index]
    if wall[index[0] + 1, index[1]]:
        down_neighbors += [(index[0] + 1, index[1])]
    else:
        down_neighbors += [i]
    if wall[index[0] - 1, index[1]]:
        top_neighbors += [(index[0] - 1, index[1])]
    else:
        top_neighbors += [i]
    if wall[index[0], index[1] - 1]:
        left_neighbors += [(index[0], index[1] - 1)]
    else:
        left_neighbors += [i]
    if wall[index[0], index[1] + 1]:
        right_neighbors += [(index[0], index[1] + 1)]
    else:
        right_neighbors += [i]
    i += 1


top_neighbors = [i if type(i) is int else indices.index(i) for i in top_neighbors]
down_neighbors = [i if type(i) is int else indices.index(i) for i in down_neighbors]
left_neighbors = [i if type(i) is int else indices.index(i) for i in left_neighbors]
right_neighbors = [i if type(i) is int else indices.index(i) for i in right_neighbors]
```

Comment: The best answer will probably depend on the nature of the computations you want to do. For example, if they can be expressed as summations over neighborhing pixels, then something like ``np.convolve`` or ``scipy.signal.fftconvolve`` can be a really nice solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it can be expressed as a convolution, in fact I will do a lot of iterations and need the updated values at each step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer will probably depend on the nature of the computations you want to do. For example, if they can be expressed as summations over neighboring pixels, then something like `np.convolve` or `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` can be a really nice solution.

For your specific question of efficiently generating arrays of neighbor indices, you might try something like this:

```
x = np.random.rand(100, 100)
mask = x > 0.9

i, j = np.where(mask)

i_neighbors = i[:, np.newaxis] + [0, 0, -1, 1]
j_neighbors = j[:, np.newaxis] + [-1, 1, 0, 0]

# need to do something with the edge cases
# the best choice will depend on your application
# here we'll change out-of-bounds neighbors to the
# central point itself.
i_neighbors = np.clip(i_neighbors, 0, 99)
j_neighbors = np.clip(j_neighbors, 0, 99)

# compute some vectorized result over the neighbors
# as a concrete example, here we'll do a standard deviation
result = x[i_neighbors, j_neighbors].std(axis=1)
```

The result is an array of values corresponding to the masked region, containing the standard deviation of neighboring values.
Hopefully that approach will work for whatever specific problem you have in mind!

---

Edit: given the edited question above, here's how my response can be adapted to generate arrays of indices in a vectorized manner:

```
x = np.random.rand(100, 100)
mask = x > -0.9

i, j = np.where(mask)

i_neighbors = i[:, np.newaxis] + [0, 0, -1, 1]
j_neighbors = j[:, np.newaxis] + [-1, 1, 0, 0]
i_neighbors = np.clip(i_neighbors, 0, 99)
j_neighbors = np.clip(j_neighbors, 0, 99)

indices = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=int)
indices[mask] = np.arange(len(i))

neighbor_in_mask = mask[i_neighbors, j_neighbors]

neighbors = np.where(neighbor_in_mask,
                     indices[i_neighbors, j_neighbors],
                     np.arange(len(i))[:, None])

left_indices, right_indices, top_indices, bottom_indices = neighbors.T
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think this is what I expected here. I need an explicit list of the indices of the neighbors in the flat array. I've added the -hopefully working- dirty solution I've written, so it's more clear (?) what output I expect. It's possible I just didn't understand your answer though. :)

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer to address the clarified question

Comment: ... and your answer is pythonic and efficient. Thanks!